Grafana iframe is not showing on Chrome mobile, but works on desktop
I use iframe calls to display graphs from Grafana within pages on my Wordpress site.
For example, on this page
https://energy-stats.uk/octopus-agile-west-midlands/

Website is hosted via 34SP hosting and the Grafana is on an Hetzner VM.
The pages (and iframes) are working perfectly fine on Chrome on PC.
But i'm finding the iframes are blank when I use Chrome on iPhone.
Is it something i'm doing wrong in my iframe code?
Curiously, this has worked for years previously, so not sure what has changed recently.
<iframe src="https://db2.energy-stats.uk/d-solo/Cl7Guo-Vk/energy-stats-uk?orgId=1&from=now-6d/d&to=now&var-area_name=Eastern_England&theme=light&panelId=4" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated.

I have checked this and it is coming fine at my end, also I have attached screenshot for your reference. https://prnt.sc/BtHZ98xv9K7i

Have you tried clearing cache and cookies on your Iphone's Chrome? Is this happening on just a single iPhone or others as well?

I have found a potential solution elsewhere, by adding more options to the iframe.
For example:
<iframe id="featured" src="https://db2.energy-stats.uk/d-solo/Cl7Guo-Vk/energy-stats-uk?orgId=1&from=now-6d/d&to=now&var-area_name=Eastern_England&theme=light&panelId=4" style="width:100%;min-height:00px;border:none;overflow-y:auto;overflow-x:hidden;" onload="this.style.height=(this.contentDocument.body.scrollHeight+15) +'px';"></iframe>

This seems really help now.
https://energy-stats.uk/octopus-agile-yorkshire/
